# Can AUTO_INCREMENT id column be used in place of DATETIME column just for ordering in SQL?

Tags: sql, sorting, indexing

In an auto-incrementing column, the newer items have higher ids. Can this property be used for sorting based on datetime? Can it potentially remove indexing in datetime column?

Comment: It depends on the precision you need for ordering and the database you are using.  Some databases cache auto-increment values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. (Unless your application is single-threaded.) Any inserts sent simultaneously over a network have no guaranteed order so the IDs generated by the auto-increment might not be monotonic with respect to any DATETIME values you might provide.